# How to insert image into into a DOORS attribute

Tags: ibm-doors

I'M probably just overlooking something obvious, but I can't figure out how to insert an image (a png of a chart created by plantuml) into a DOORS attribute.

If I drag and drop the image into the attribute, it wants to create an external link to the image on my hard drive. If I start editing the attribute, and drag the image into the editor, it just shows an image icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Insert > Picture and selecting your PNG (you'll need to switch to 'all files' as the type)